# Left multiplication proof with residue classes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

[image]

Can't figure out where to start on this problem. I keep thinking of the example modulo 2 and that it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is easy to get lost in notation. Let me ask you this, if we have a function between sets of finite, equal size that is not a surjection, can it be an injection? And if $L_{[a]}$ is not an injection, what can be say about the kernal? But what is the definition of kernal in this case?

Comment: Aren't residue classes infinite sets?

Comment: A lot (if not, most) of the time we don't care that residue classes are infinite sets. You should simply think of them as "new objects" that can be multiplied in the given well-defined manner.

Comment: Residue classes are infinite sets, but the set of residue classes, which is what you care about, is finite.

Comment: And by the way, you should think modulo 4 or 6 instead of 2, for instance.

Comment: Okay I understand why it is not injective but how does that show that there is a [b] such that [a][b]=[0]